# How can I color a title in django's sqlite database?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

When I add a new card I would like that every time I can choose the title color. This is my code:

```
from django.db import models

#Create your models here.
class Aziende(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prezzo = models.FloatField()
    descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

How can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can fix this in two ways:

1. we store the color in a separate field; or
2. we write the title in HTML syntax and then render this in the template.

## Option 1: storing the color in a field

You can add a `ColorField` to your model from the [**`django-colorfield`** package](https://pypi.org/project/django-colorfield/). You install this with:

```
pip3 install django-colorfield
```

we can then add the `colorfield` app to the `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
# settings.py

# …

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'colorfield',
    # …
]

# …
```

Next we can add a `ColorField` to your model:

```
from colorfield.fields import ColorField
from django.db import models

class Aziende(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prezzo = models.FloatField()
    descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    nome_color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Then in the template, we can render the title with the given color. For example:

```
<p color="{{ item.nome_color }}"> {{ item.nome }}</p>
```

## Option 2: storing HTML as title

We can also decide to store HTML data in the `nome` field. In that case we thus do *not* add an extra field to the model. We can use the [**`mark_safe`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) function to prevent Django from escaping the HTML code, so:

```
from colorfield.fields import ColorField
from django.db import models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class Aziende(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prezzo = models.FloatField()
    descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return mark_safe(self.nome)
```

We can then render the `nome` of the `Aziende` object with:

```
{{ aziende_item }}
```

or we can use the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to prevent escaping the name:

```
{{ aziende_item.nome|safe }}
```

Comment: You are using a `BorsaConfigcolorfield` (??) instead of a `ColorField`, so likely you did something wrong when altering your model.

Comment: Yes, fortunately I solved that problem, but now I get a tiny and not colored writing. What can I do? Thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Store the color as a hex code in a CharField:

```
class Aziende(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prezzo = models.FloatField()
    descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    colore = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='#FFFFFF')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Then display it in your template:

```
<h1 class="title" style="color: {{azienda.colore}}" >{{azienda.nome}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another app call it color, and another model call it Color, then in your current model u just add a foreignkey like this:

```
from django.db import models
from color.models import Color

#Create your models here.

class Aziende(models.Model):
   color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) #Color is your new model
```

in your new model.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Color(models.Model):
    color=models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color
```

This way you can add any color you wish later on and then be able to choose it anytime you add it.

Comment: @JacobBrown Glad to help